# Запуск mplayer в php

Tags: php, exec

На ubuntu есть .sh файл, который запускает плеер и выполняет еще несколько нужных команд. При запуске из консоли работает отлично, а при запуске из пхп выдает все что угодно (информацию о текущем состоянии кеша для mplayer, ругается на отсутствие субтитров), но не запускает плеер. Проблем с правами нет.

Для запуска использовал такие конструкции:

```
echo exec('/path/file.sh < /dev/null &');
```

Конкретно в этом случае, пхп выводит:

> "Exiting... (End of file)"

или, в случае, если я пытаюсь запустить проигрывание файла через пхп:

> "Load subtitles in /home/parallels/video/"

Прав для `www-data` должно хватать. Во всяком случае, если бы не хватало, то в результате была бы одна и та же ошибка. Такое ощущение, что плеер просто в фоне запускается (и скрипты тоже). Как можно проверить, хватает ли прав, или может как то можно принудительно запускать НЕ в фоне?

Comment: Может вы запускаете процесс от другого пользователя, либо с другими переменными среды

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, вывод PHP. И содержимое лога ошибок.

Comment: Возможно не хватает из под пользователя www-data прав доступа? Или окружение настроено неправильно.

Answer (score 1):

Он у вас в фоне и запускается. Уберите & в конце вызова.

```
echo exec('/path/file.sh < /dev/null', $output );
var_export($output);
```

Если все равно ошибки, приведите сюда вывод $output.

Comment: Load subtitles in /home/parallels/www/temp/array ( 0 => 'MPlayer 1.1-4.8 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team', 1 => 'Terminal type `unknown\' is not defined.', 2 => '', 3 => 'Playing /home/parallels/www/temp/p01.mp4.', 4 => 'libavformat version 54.20.4 (external)', 5 => 'Mismatching header version 54.20.3', 6 => 'libavformat file format detected.', 7 => '[lavf] stream 0: video (h264), -vid 0', 8 => '[lavf] stream 1: audio (aac)...

Comment: А не в контексте скрипта, напрямую из консоли mplayer нормально запускается? Судя по ошибке проблемы с аудио.

Comment: Да, напрямую запускается, все отлично срабатывает. Еще пишет "'Terminal type `unknown\' is not defined.'"